# How will Touch of Slime react if it encounters Acid Resistance

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I have a creature with *acid resistance 5* and make a successful touch attack with [Touch of Slime](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateMagic/spells/touchOfSlime.html). What is happening?

The description to the spell does not mention *acid*. They just talk about [green slime](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/environment.html#green-slime) but a component to build the slime is *a drop of acid*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Touch of slime* does not interact with acid [resistance](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/universalMonsterRules.html#resistance). The spell does not have the [acid] descriptor, and none of the damage it does is called out to be acid damage (nor is the damage caused by an actual [green slime](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/environment.html#green-slime)).

Furthermore, ability damage generally doesn't have a type and is therefore unaffected by resistances.